# Render Images on iOS 14 Widgets

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I'm developing a iOS 14 Widget extension.

I have 3 images to show in loop and creating a Timeline to show those images.

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [ImageEntry] = []
    let currentDate = Date()
    
    for i in 1 ..< 4 {
        let imageNumber = String(i)
        let currentImage = "image_" + imageNumber
        let entry = ImageEntry(date: currentDate,image: currentImage)
        entries.append(entry)
    }

    let nextUpdateDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: currentDate)!
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextUpdateDate))

    completion(timeline)
}


struct WidgetModuleEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    Image(entry.image)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

First image always rendering but subsequent images are not.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constucting timeline you need to specify explicit entry date for each entry. The policy parameter is for *recreating* next timeline.

So your `getTimeline` should look like

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [ImageEntry] = []
    let currentDate = Date()

    for i in 1 ..< 4 {
        let imageNumber = String(i)
        let currentImage = "image_" + imageNumber
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: (i-1)*5, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = ImageEntry(date: entryDate, image: currentImage)
        entries.append(entry)
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

Comment: No content rendering. Could problem be related to `EntryView`? `struct WidgetModuleEntryView : View { var entry: Provider.Entry var body: some View { Image(entry.image) .resizable() .scaledToFill() }}`

Comment: I missed that your range starts from 1, so first image will be shown after 5 mins. See corrected.

Comment: Still no content rendering.

Comment: I replicated this scenario locally - all works fine (just used .second for faster iteration). Xcode 12GM / iOS 14.

Comment: The images were not properly added to the project. It's working now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is one issue with this approach: If I use  `(i-1)*1` with `.minute`, last image skip shorter than 1 minute, If I use  `(i-1)*1` with `.second`, last image skip longer than 1 second.

Comment: You can try to change timeline creation policiy giving time *after* last item, like `.after(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: entries.last!.date)!`