# Can't refresh WidgetView every minute

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I can't refresh my widgets every minute. Here is my getTimeline function;

```
let currentDate = Date()
let refreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
guard let widget = try? JSONDecoder().decode([myWidgets].self, from: widgetData)
let entry = widgetEntry(date: Date(), widget: widget[0])
let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(refreshDate))
completion(timeline)
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

I also tried refreshing every second with only refresing the date to show current time, but its stops refreshing after couple of seconds.

Then I tried this code below from @pawello2222 but widgets are not loading correctly with it;

```
    var entries = [widgetEntry]()
    let currentDate = Date()
    let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
    let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

    for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
        guard let widget = try? JSONDecoder().decode([myWidgets].self, from: widgetData)
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
        entries.append(widgetEntry(date: entryDate, widget: widget[0]))
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
    completion(timeline)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64086553/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi I tried that solution, everything working great without images. But when I put a background Image or even a system image on a HStack, its not rendering, only the placeholder.

Comment: I don't see any image in your code snapshot. Would you provide reproducible example based on what you commented above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also tried refreshing every second with only refresing the date to
> show current time, but its stops refreshing after couple of seconds.

You only have a limited number of *refreshes* available to your Widget. If you call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` every second, your Widget is likely to run out of available updates very quickly.

---

Also, you shouldn't call `reloadAllTimelines()` in `getTimeline()`:

```
...
completion(timeline)
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() // remove this
```

---

> Then I tried this code below from @pawello2222 but widgets are not
> loading correctly with it

I assume you're referring to this answer: [Updating time text label each minute in WidgetKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64054719/8697793)

Note that in your code `guard let` may not pass through:

```
for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
    guard let widget = try? JSONDecoder().decode([myWidgets].self, from: widgetData) // you need `else { ... return }` here
    let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
    entries.append(widgetEntry(date: entryDate, widget: widget[0]))
}
```

See: [When to use guard let rather than if let](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-to-use-guard-let-rather-than-if-let)

Comment: I think the problem is in my view. After trying your suggestion it worked in a simple view with only image and time. Do you know anyway to update the widget data whenever the JSONDecoder data changes?

Comment: @BaturayKoç It depends on how/when the data changes. In your question there is no information as to what the `myWidgets` variable is. I suggest you create a new question describing your issue. I'll try to help you there.